# Kotlin Multiplatform + Sentry

Tags: android, gradle, sentry, kotlin-multiplatform

I want to use Sentry for my Multiplatform Kotlin project.

[Sentry for Kotlin Multiplatform](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-kotlin-multiplatform)

So I was trying to prepare the setup of Sentry with Kotlin Multiplatform.
I was following the guide, made a mavenLocal() build etc.
Now I wanted to add it to the project.
However, when starting my (Android) project, even before starting the onCreate() of the Application I get a crash stating:

```
Unable to get provider io.sentry.android.core.SentryInitProvider: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DSN is required. Use empty string to disable SDK.
```

So to be clear this happens already when adding `api("io.sentry:sentry-kotlin-multiplatform:0.0.1")` to the dependencies. Long before the init call.

All I did was:

1. Configure shared `build.gradle.kts` and add

```
 val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                api("io.sentry:sentry-kotlin-multiplatform:0.0.1")
```

2. Adding the sample configuration

```
fun initializeSentry(context: Context) {
    Sentry.init(context) { sentryOptions ->  setDsnHere... } 
}
```

and in the Android Application:

```
initializeSentry(this)
```

Then tried to run it. But I don't even get to the init call.
The configuration should be reached and the `initializeSentry(this)` block executed. (I can accept if it fails there but I don't even get that far.)

Instead the app fails stating

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: xyz, PID: 23056
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider io.sentry.android.core.SentryInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DSN is required. Use empty string to disable SDK.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7467)
        ...
```

even before anything else.
So the mere adding to the gradle file causes the crash already (even if the other code is commented out).

-------- Full Stack trace-------

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider io.sentry.android.core.SentryInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DSN is required. Use empty string to disable SDK.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7467)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6973)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6744)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2133)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)

     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DSN is required. Use empty string to disable SDK.
        at io.sentry.Sentry.initConfigurations(Sentry.java:201)
        at io.sentry.Sentry.init(Sentry.java:170)
        at io.sentry.Sentry.init(Sentry.java:118)
        at io.sentry.android.core.SentryAndroid.init(SentryAndroid.java:87)
        at io.sentry.android.core.SentryAndroid.init(SentryAndroid.java:56)
        at io.sentry.android.core.SentryInitProvider.onCreate(SentryInitProvider.java:27)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2451)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2421)
        at io.sentry.android.core.SentryInitProvider.attachInfo(SentryInitProvider.java:44)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7462)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6973) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6744) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2133) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the manual had forgotten to mention the auto configuration.

Add this line to your Manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="io.sentry.auto-init" android:value="false" />
```

and proceed with the tutorial.

### For Reference:

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-kotlin-multiplatform/issues/45